# importxml how to retrieve the bitcoin price

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I need to import to google sheets, the price of bitcoin in Argentine pesos from this website [criptoya.com](https://criptoya.com/)

I'm trying this on a cell:

```
=ImportXML("https://www.criptoya.com", "//td/@id='lac'")
```

Or

```
=ImportXML("https://www.criptoya.com", "@id='lac'")
```

with no success, can you help me out?

BTW I also know that there is an API for that website but I don't know how to use it.

```
https://criptoya.com/api/
```

Answer (score 0):

From having a look at the website it seems that all the prices are being loaded with Javascript which may present problems to parsing the data from Google Sheets.

I would advise staying away from parsing public websites, they could change the website at any moment and force you to fix all the rules again.

You could use a simple API like this to get Bitcoin (or any other coin) price in USD

`=IMPORTDATA("https://cryptoprices.cc/BTC/")`

Then convert to Argentina Pesos ARS using Google's native function

`=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDARS")`